# Compare nth row with n+1 th row and if it lies in range of n th row print n+1 row USNG ORACLE QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like

```
ID     name   Start_no     End_no
1       a       2           123  
2       b       3           65
3       c       191         199
4       d       201         225
5       e       220         223
6       f       221         224
```

I tried:

```
SELECT  *   
  FROM IV_STOCK_DETAILS a
 where  a.STOCK_START_NO in ( select b.stock_end_no
                                from IV_STOCK_DETAILS B
                               where b.stock_start_no between a.stock_start_no 
                                                          AND A.STOCK_END_NO 
                                 AND B.STOCK_END_NO BETWEEN a.stock_start_no 
                                                        AND A.STOCK_END_NO  
                                 AND (a.stock_start_no - A.STOCK_END_NO) !=0  
                            )
ORDER BY cod_stock_branch, stock_start_no;
```

so I need to check all rows one by one with its previous rows and if its `start_no` and `end_no` lies within `start_no` and `end_no` of previous one print row. In this case answer will be rows no 2, 5, 6.. I need only query.

Comment: By the way, you might want to pick a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `LAG` function or Oracle, which gives you access to the previous row.

And, you should only get row 2 and 5 from your table, as per the requirements you have, since row 6 has `end_no` as 224, which is not less than `end_no` of row5 which is `223`

```
SELECT id, name, start_no, end_no 
FROM (
    SELECT id, name, start_no, end_no, 
           lag(start_no, 1, 0) over (order by id) prev_start_no ,
           lag(end_no, 1, 0) over (order by id) prev_end_no
    FROM test
) 
WHERE start_no BETWEEN prev_start_no AND prev_end_no
AND end_no BETWEEN prev_start_no AND prev_end_no;
```

Comment: Just make sure that you change the table name and column names as per the ones in your database and then execute it.

Comment: its working ,but i dont knw from where its fetching result. the answer is not what this is showing,its else.!!! may be i think i didnt get the question from my mentor properly!!becos logic wise you are right,but actual answer is not this!!!

Comment: What is the "actual answer" you're expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Joins to the rescue! Join the table to itself on the previous ID and include the range test in the join.

```
SELECT iv.*
  FROM IV_STOCK_DETAILS AS iv
    JOIN IV_STOCK_DETAILS AS ivprev ON iv.id=ivprev.id+1
         AND ivprev.Start_no <= iv.Start_no
         AND iv.End_no <= ivprev.End_no
```

Comment: "not working" tells us nothing. When describing an issue, explain what you expect and what you actually get, which includes any error messages.

Comment: i meant iot gave me error ORA-1722 invalid number. let me remind you id is integer just here,in actual table its alphanumeric. sorry fr inconvenience.

Comment: @user3264817: that's not a reminder, that's new information. [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be representative, so the sample ID column should be of the same type as the real ID column. Note that rows aren't intrinsically ordered in the relational model, so there's no intrinsic concept of "previous row". You'll have to define that in your query, as I did with `iv.id=ivprev.id+1`.