# Compare nth row with n+1 th row and if it lies in range of n th row print n+1th row USNG ORACLE QUERY only

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like

```
    Id     name     stock_stat_no     stock_end_no
----------------------------------------------------
    1       a            2                  123
    2       b            3                  65
    3       c            191                199
    4       d            201                225
    5       e            220                223
    6       f            221                224
```

I tried

```
 SELECT  *   FROM IV_STOCK_DETAILS a
  where  a.STOCK_START_NO in
     (select b.stock_end_no
        from IV_STOCK_DETAILS B
       where b.stock_start_no 
       between a.stock_start_no AND
             A.STOCK_END_NO 
         AND B.STOCK_END_NO BETWEEN a.stock_start_no AND A.STOCK_END_NO  
         AND (a.stock_start_no - A.STOCK_END_NO) !=0  
         )
  ORDER BY cod_stock_branch, stock_start_no;
```

So I need to check all rows one by one with its previous rows and if it starts now and end no lies within start & end no of previous one print row. In this case the answer will be
Row no 2,5,6..

I NEED ONLY QUERY

Comment: You just asked this question!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545223/compare-nth-row-with-n1-th-row-and-if-it-lies-in-range-of-n-th-row-print-n1-ro

Comment: Why 2,5,6? Only 2 and 5 fill those criteria.

Comment: -1 for re-posting the exact same question only 30minutes later

Comment: Two people answered your other question.  You said "not working" to both of them, without providing further details.  One of them even provided a SQL Fiddle to demonstrate that their solution worked.  Instead of engaging with those people you have re-posted your question and two more people have wasted their time providing similar answers.  Poor show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT b.id 
FROM   iv_stock_details a, 
       iv_stock_details b 
WHERE  a.id + 1 = b.id 
       AND b.stock_stat_no >= a.stock_stat_no 
       AND b.stock_stat_no < a.stock_end_no 
       AND b.stock_end_no <= a.stock_end_no 
       AND b.stock_end_no > a.stock_stat_no;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94722/7

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *analytic functions* **Lead/Lag**.

The exact problem, IMHO, is unclear: what is "*range*", what is "*row lies in range*" (*a field* can be in a *range*).

So let's, re-state the problem; instead of "*Compare nth row with n+1 th row and if it lies in range of n th row print n+1th*"

I'll use (possible) equivalent: "*Select row iff a prior row range [stock_stat_no..stock_end_no] intersect the range [stock_stat_no..stock_end_no] of current one (rows ordered by name)*"

```
select id
  from (select id as id,
               name as name,
               stock_stat_no as stock_stat_no,
               stock_end_no as stock_end_no,  
               Lag(stock_stat_no) over(order by name) as prior_stock_stat_no,
               Lag(stock_end_no) over(order by name) as prior_stock_end_no  
          from IV_STOCK_DETAILS)
 where (prior_stock_stat_no >= stock_stat_no) and 
       (prior_stock_stat_no <= stock_end_no) or
       (stock_stat_no >= prior_stock_stat_no) and 
       (stock_stat_no <= prior_stock_end_no)
```

Comment: I tried this query in SQLFiddle... seems like it doesn't produce any results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/94722/2

Comment: @maythesource.com: I'm sorry for the error, but the question was stated unclear: it's intersection that's looked for, not "lies in the range". I've edited the post, now "2, 5, 6" is the answer